# php don't show duplicate id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

First sorry for my English, and thanks for your help.

I try to explain.

I have 3 table

```
miele
CREATE TABLE `miele` (
`id`(11) INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datamiele` DATE NOT NULL  ,
`codmiele` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL  ,
`postazimiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`nomemiele` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL  ,
`totmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`resultmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`resmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`notemiele` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL  ,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

confmiele
CREATE TABLE `confmiele` (
`idconf` INT(11) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dataconfmiele` DATE NOT NULL  ,
`codconfmiele` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL  ,
`nomeconfmiele` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL  ,
`boxconfmiele` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL  ,
`pesoconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`numconfmiele` INT(4) NOT NULL  ,
`totconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`resparzconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`tottotconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`resultconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`resconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`totnumconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`resultnumconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`resnumconfmiele` INT(7) NOT NULL  ,
`noteconfmiele` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL  ,
PRIMARY KEY  (`idconf`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


fattmiele
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fattmiele` (

`idfatt` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`datafattmiele` date NOT NULL,

`tipodocfattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`numfattmiele` int(10) NOT NULL,

`nomedittfattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`denodittfattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`pivadittfattmiele` varchar(11) NOT NULL,

`codfisdittfattmiele` varchar(16) NOT NULL,

 `ibamdittfattmiele` varchar(27) NOT NULL,

`abancdittfattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`viadittfattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`cittadittfattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`provdittfattmiele` varchar(3) NOT NULL,

`capdittfattmiele` int(5) NOT NULL,

`nazdittfattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`teldittfattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`celdittfattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`emaildittfattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`nomeclifattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`denoclifattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`pivaclifattmiele` varchar(11) NOT NULL,

`codfisclifattmiele` varchar(16) NOT NULL,

`viaclifattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`cittaclifattmiele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`provclifattmiele` varchar(3) NOT NULL,

`capclifattmiele` int(5) NOT NULL,

`nazclifattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`telclifattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`dest1clifattmiele` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

`noteproddittfattmiele` varchar(300) NOT NULL,

`pagfattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`cod1conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome1conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome1sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg1sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`resparz1sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`eurokg1sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`box1conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso1conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num1conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot1pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend1numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit1eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro1fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod2conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome2conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome2sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg2sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`resparz2sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`eurokg2sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`box2conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso2conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num2conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot2pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend2numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit2eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro2fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod3conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome3conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome3sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg3sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg3sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz3sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box3conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso3conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num3conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot3pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend3numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit3eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro3fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod4conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome4conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome4sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg4sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg4sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz4sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box4conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso4conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num4conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot4pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend4numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit4eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro4fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod5conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome5conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome5sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg5sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg5sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz5sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box5conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso5conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num5conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot5pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend5numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit5eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro5fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod6conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome6conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome6sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg6sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg6sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz6sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box6conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso6conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num6conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot6pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend6numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit6eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro6fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod7conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome7conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome7sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg7sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg7sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz7sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box7conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso7conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num7conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot7pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend7numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit7eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro7fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod8conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome8conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome8sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg8sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg8sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz8sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box8conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso8conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num8conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot8pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend8numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit8eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro8fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod9conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome9conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome9sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg9sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg9sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz9sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box9conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso9conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num9conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot9pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend9numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit9eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro9fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod10conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome10conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome10sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg10sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg10sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz10sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box10conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso10conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num10conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot10pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend10numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit10eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro10fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod11conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome11conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome11sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg11sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg11sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz11sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box11conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso11conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num11conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot11pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend11numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit11eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro11fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod12conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome12conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome12sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg12sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg12sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz12sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box12conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso12conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num12conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot12pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend12numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit12eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro12fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod13conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome13conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome13sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg13sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg13sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz13sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box13conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso13conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num13conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot13pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend13numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit13eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro13fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod14conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome14conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome14sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg14sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg14sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz14sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box14conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso14conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num14conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot14pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend14numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit14eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro14fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod15conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome15conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome15sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg15sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg15sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz15sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box15conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso15conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num15conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot15pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend15numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit15eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro15fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod16conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome16conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome16sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg16sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg16sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz16sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box16conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso16conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num16conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot16pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend16numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit16eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro16fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod17conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome17conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome17sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg17sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg17sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz17sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box17conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso17conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num17conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot17pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend17numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit17eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro17fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod18conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome18conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome18sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg18sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg18sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz18sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box18conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso18conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num18conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot18pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend18numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit18eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro18fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod19conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome19conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome19sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg19sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg19sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz19sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box19conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso19conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num19conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot19pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend19numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit19eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro19fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`cod20conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome20conffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`nome20sfusofattmiele` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

`kg20sfusofattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`eurokg20sfusofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`resparz20sfusofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`box20conffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`peso20conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`num20conffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`tot20pesoconffattmiele` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,

`vend20numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`unit20eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`euro20fattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,

`sommafattmiele` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,

`impfattmiele` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,

`valscontofattmiele` int(2) NOT NULL,

`scontofattmiele` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,

`valtaxfattmiele` int(2) NOT NULL,

`taxfattmiele` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,

`toteurofattmiele` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,

`traspfattmiele` varchar(25) NOT NULL,

`numcollofattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,

`collotipofattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`idfatt`)

) ENGINE=MyISAM  
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;
```

I create a form for have this result:

- Select all record by the 3 tables in order by `datamiele, dataconf, datafatt`.
- Where from table `miele`, `nomemiele` and `codmiele` like `$myvalue`.
- Where from table `confmiele`, `nomeconfmiele` and `codconfmiele` like `$myvalue`.
- Where from table `fattmiele`, `nome1conffattmiele` and `cod1conffattmiele` like `$myvalue` or nome2conffattmiele and cod2confattmiele like $myvalue etc for 20 cod and name.

Yes I know the next step is separated `fattmiele` in two table, one with product e, one for data of invoice. But first I want resolving the problem so, I tried the first with 2 of the 3 table.

```
$query="SELECT miele.* , confmiele.*  FROM miele , confmiele WHERE 
  datamiele  BETWEEN ('".$datamieleusDA."') AND  ('".$datamieleusA."') AND dataconfmiele  BETWEEN ('".$datamieleusDA."') AND  ('".$datamieleusA."')
  AND codmiele LIKE ('".$codmiele."') AND nomemiele LIKE ('".$nomemiele."') AND codconfmiele LIKE ('".$codmiele."') AND nomeconfmiele LIKE ('".$nomemiele."')   ORDER BY 2 ";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());
{    
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
```

Work's but I see duplicate id for each data from `confmiele` always repeat the `miele` data.

Some can help me please.

Some solution or MySQL or PHP ways.

Please I hope you forgive me for my English and be patient.

Comment: Lengthiest question I ever see. Not read yet :p

Comment: Uh...please work on the formatting of your question. Indent the sourcecode by four spaces to make it more readable. I'll not even bother to do it myself...way too much work. ;)

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal you should get a medal for formatting all of that!

Comment: I have the impression you have no link between your tables in your SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

Explain it shortly and clearly.No one has the patience to read this messy post.